# Why do I have Android Google Play account picker loop?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I would like to implement Google Play Services in my android application.
I've implemented [manual sign in](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin) there - user should press the button in the  `GameSignInActivity` to log in.

But it doesn't work as expected. When I press the sign in button, it shows list of accounts to pick. Once account is chosen and OK is pressed, it closes its activity and then shows an account picker again (and it happens again and again).

Here is the log:

```
05-28 18:39:54.329: W/BaseGameActivity(31235): BaseGameActivity.enabledDebugLog(bool,String) is deprecated. Use enableDebugLog(boolean)
05-28 18:39:54.329: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: Debug log enabled.
05-28 18:39:54.329: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: Setup: requested clients: 1
05-28 18:39:54.909: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: onStart
05-28 18:39:54.909: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: Connecting client.
05-28 18:39:55.170: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: onConnectionFailed
05-28 18:39:55.170: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: Connection failure:
05-28 18:39:55.170: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper:    - code: SIGN_IN_REQUIRED(4)
05-28 18:39:55.180: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper:    - resolvable: true
05-28 18:39:55.180: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper:    - details: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{4052a0c0: android.os.BinderProxy@40526538}}
05-28 18:39:55.180: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: onConnectionFailed: Will NOT resolve; not user-initiated and max attempts reached: 1 >= 0
05-28 18:39:55.180: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: onConnectionFailed: since we won't resolve, failing now.
05-28 18:39:55.180: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: Notifying LISTENER of sign-in FAILURE (no error)
05-28 18:39:55.180: I/GameSignInActivity(31235): Sign in failed
05-28 18:39:55.200: I/ActivityManager(559): Displayed org.myapp/.GameSignInActivity: +946ms

05-28 18:40:12.907: I/GameSignInActivity(31235): Begin user sign in
05-28 18:40:12.917: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: beginUserInitiatedSignIn: resetting attempt count.
05-28 18:40:12.957: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: Starting USER-INITIATED sign-in flow.
05-28 18:40:12.967: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: beginUserInitiatedSignIn: continuing pending sign-in flow.
05-28 18:40:12.997: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: resolveConnectionResult: trying to resolve result: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{4052a0c0: android.os.BinderProxy@40526538}}
05-28 18:40:13.007: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: Result has resolution. Starting it.
05-28 18:40:13.007: I/ActivityManager(559): Starting activity: Intent { flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity (has extras) } from pid -1
05-28 18:40:13.257: I/ActivityManager(559): Start proc com.google.android.gms.ui for activity com.google.android.gms/.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity: pid=31502 uid=10033 gids={3003, 1015, 1006, 1007, 2001, 3002, 3001}
05-28 18:40:13.507: I/MultiDex(31502): load(/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1.apk, forceReload=false)
05-28 18:40:13.638: I/MultiDex(31502): Need extracted file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-1.apk.classes2.zip
05-28 18:40:13.638: I/MultiDex(31502): No extraction needed for /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/secondary-dexes/com.google.android.gms-1.apk.classes2.zip of size 1897418
05-28 18:40:13.728: D/GCM(24534): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE
05-28 18:40:14.328: I/ActivityManager(559): Displayed com.google.android.gms/.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity: +1s83ms (total +17s59ms)
05-28 18:40:18.612: I/ActivityManager(559): Starting activity: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.common.account.CHOOSE_ACCOUNT flg=0x20000000 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.account.AccountPickerActivity (has extras) } from pid 31502
05-28 18:40:18.973: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: onStop
05-28 18:40:18.973: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: Client already disconnected when we got onStop.
05-28 18:40:18.993: I/ActivityManager(559): Displayed com.google.android.gms/.common.account.AccountPickerActivity: +310ms
05-28 18:40:21.395: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: onStart
05-28 18:40:21.395: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: Connecting client.
05-28 18:40:21.565: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: onConnectionFailed
05-28 18:40:21.565: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: Connection failure:
05-28 18:40:21.585: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper:    - code: SIGN_IN_REQUIRED(4)
05-28 18:40:21.595: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper:    - resolvable: true
05-28 18:40:21.595: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper:    - details: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{405ecb30: android.os.BinderProxy@40526538}}
05-28 18:40:21.595: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: onConnectionFailed: WILL resolve because user initiated sign-in.
05-28 18:40:21.595: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: onConnectionFailed: resolving problem...
05-28 18:40:21.595: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: resolveConnectionResult: trying to resolve result: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{405ecb30: android.os.BinderProxy@40526538}}
05-28 18:40:21.595: D/GameHelper(31235): GameHelper: Result has resolution. Starting it.
05-28 18:40:21.625: I/ActivityManager(559): Starting activity: Intent { flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity (has extras) } from pid -1
05-28 18:40:25.569: I/ActivityManager(559): Starting activity: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.common.account.CHOOSE_ACCOUNT flg=0x20000000 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.account.AccountPickerActivity (has extras) } from pid 31502
```

What should I do to fix it?

P.S. `android:minSdkVersion` is `7` for my app, and I test the app on the device with android 2.3. I also use `android-support-v4.jar` lib.
I don't have such problem with the emulator running android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem until I looked at LogCat:

```
Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/[longNumber]?language=en_US
Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.
...
Unable to sign in - application does not have a registered client ID
```

Turned out I had signed the application and then generated an SHA1 key, but later used a newer AndroidSDK and the SHA1 key changed, so the developer console couldn't recognize it. Check out your log and see if that's that same error, and if it is, remove your App from the console and sign it again.

If you haven't authorized it before, you can check out [this guide](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/google-play-game-services-leaderboards--cms-20700), it was helpful